# How it is possible to passthrough file in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to passthrough a file in logstash for debugging purposes. Is it possible somehow?

If i use following config to stdout stdin input, it works fine:

```
input { stdin { } } 
output { stdout { } }
```

But when i want to do the same for file, it does not work:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/home/logstash/xunit.json"]
  }
} 

output { 
  stdout { } 
}
```

I only see following warning, and nothing more:

```
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
```

What i am doing wrong?

P.S. If using verbose mode, i see following lines, then everything hangs:

```
Registering file input {:path=>["/home/logstash/xunit.json"], :level=>:info}
Pipeline started {:level=>:info}
```

P.P.S. User has access to file.

Comment: Is stuff being written to xunit.json for logstash to process it?

Comment: @AlainCollins yes, i need xunit info in kibana web interface

Comment: Can the user who is running Logstash read /home/logstash/xunit.json? You'll have to enable verbose logs with `--verbose` to see read access problems.

Comment: @MagnusBäck sure, it can.